# GWT change Jetty version

Tags: gwt, jetty, atmosphere

I want to change GWT's `v. 2.7.0` embedded Jetty version `v. 8.1.12.v20130726` to later jetty `v. 9.2.22.v20170606`, because for some reason [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/)
websockets do not work with jetty 8 version (while it works with 9).

To make sure that it's Jetty that's causing problems for Atmosphere (and not GWT super dev mode), I deployed application.war to tomcat/Jetty servers:

- Tomcat 7.0.79: works
- Jetty 9.2.22.v20170606: works
- Jetty 8.1.12.v20130726: does not work

I found a thread asking quite a similar question, [GWT: Jetty version in dev mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592108/gwt-jetty-version-in-dev-mode), and I would like to expand on that. If I were to implement [ServletContainerLauncher](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/ext/ServletContainerLauncher.html) , would it not conflict with [JettyLauncher](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/javadoc/gwt-2.6.1/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/JettyLauncher.html) ? How should I go about writting my own `ServletCotainerLauncher` for dev mode?

If you have any better ideas then writing my own ServletContainerLauncher, I would like to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT 2.8 underwent specific modifications to make this possible - it wasn't simple, though if you review the commits, you could probably make the same changes.

Instead, I strongly urge you to consider moving to GWT 2.8.2, the latest version of GWT, released just a few days ago. The version you are using, GWT 2.7.0, is almost three years old, and has a number of other bugs that have been resolved since then.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing GWT version is not an option at this time.

Comment: The customizations are not small, but it is possible to do. Not the kind of thing I can detail in a stackoverflow answer though, but reviewing the commit log for 2.8.0 would be a good first step. The ServletContainerLauncher would likewise be somewhat difficult to keep the classpaths separate, it might be easier to just modify the 2.7.0 build.

Comment: I was wondering, is there any huge changes between Jetty version 8 and 9? If there is not, and if Jetty 9 is compatible with gwt 2.7, maybe changing Jetty version in gwt dev buil.xml might simple be enough? (with some changes build does not compile)

Comment: do you by any chance know where (if) I could find release notes from 2.7 -> 2.8.2? Or can you point out some major changes? (excluding Jetty version change ofc) (Nevermind, found the notes http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_0)

Comment: Here is the full list of commits between 2.7.0 and 2.8.0 - just change the end of the url to keep going to 2.8.2 https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+log/2.7.0..2.8.0